# What is the most suitable battery for an inverter?

Tags: batteries, inverter

I was thinking about making a small inverter project but I don't know what type of batteries is most suitable for this application. Anyways, I know the capacity(20Ah) but i don't know what type do I choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a 20 Ah battery, I'd suggest some form of lead-acid battery.  They are fairly easy to charge, and not hazardous if you overcharge or mistreat them.